# I'm getting accidental selections through a model. How do I prevent this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, selection-tools

I'm a newb following the donut tutorial. I'm at the stage of modeling the dribbles from the icing. I'm in Edit mode with X-ray vision off, and solid mode active in the view port. When I try to select vertices on the near side of the object one's on the other side also get selected. Confusingly this doesn't happen all the time and I can't see what is different between the times this happens and the times it does not. Can anyone explain what's happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, maybe you've activated transparency (X Ray), what does it give if you press Alt Z?

Comment: Alt Z does switch me between X-ray mode and not, but I don't think thats the issue. It was deffinatly happening while I wasn't in X-ray mode.